# ¿Cómo cancelar tarea asíncrona en Asp.Net Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Escribi este codigo para cancelar una tarea asincrona pero no la esta cancelando:

```
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private CancellationToken _ct1;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private CancellationToken _ct2;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private CancellationToken _ct3;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts4 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private CancellationToken _ct4;

   public ActionResult Report(ReportFilterModel filterModel, int report)
        {
            if (Session["GeneratingReport"] == null || !(bool)Session["GeneratingReport"])
            {
                _cts1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _ct1 = _cts1.Token;
                _cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _ct2 = _cts2.Token;
                _cts3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _ct3 = _cts3.Token;
                _cts4 = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _ct4 = _cts4.Token;

                Session["GeneratingReport"] = true; //Se registra en sesión
                string basePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseFilePath"] + "/ReportesExcel/";
                string fileName = null;
                try {
                    switch (report)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            fileName = "report-users" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReport(filterModel, basePath + fileName,_ct1),_ct1);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            fileName = "report-plays" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                           Task T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReportPlays(filterModel, basePath + fileName,_ct2), _ct2);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            fileName = "reporte-compras" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReportPurchases(filterModel, basePath + fileName,_ct3), _ct3);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            fileName = "reporte-ventas-distribuidor" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReportDistributorPurchases(filterModel, basePath + fileName,_ct4), _ct4);
                            break;
                    }
                    Session["ReportPath"] = basePath + fileName;
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                { 
                    string error =  ex.ToString();
                }
                
            }
            return Content("Generando Reporte");
        }
```

Aqui un ejemplo del metodo que invoco:

```
public async Task ExportReport(ReportFilterModel filterModel, string path, CancellationToken _ct)
    {
        try
        {

            while (!_ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using (var taskDb = new CmsLiteData()) //Se define contexto de ejecución de la conexión para la tarea Asyncrona, forzando la llamada de dispose cuando finalice
                {
                    this.GenerateExcel(filterModel, "Informe compra y recompra (cantidad de usuarios únicos)", true, path, taskDb);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _cts1.Cancel();
            CmsHelper.SetLog(ex.ToString(), 1, "PurchaseReportController", "ExportReport", "TareaAsincrona", "N/A", "N/A");
        }
    }
```

Aqui el metodo desde donde trato de cancela no devuelve error pero no cancela la tarea:

```
  public ActionResult CancelTaskGenerateReport (int idReport)
        {
            string nameReport = string.Empty;
            switch (idReport)
            {
                case 1:
                    nameReport = "Reporte de compra/recompra";
                    _cts1.Cancel();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    nameReport = "Reporte de reproducciones";
                    _cts2.Cancel();
                    break;
                case 3:
                     nameReport = "Reporte de compra";
                    _cts3.Cancel();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    nameReport = "Reporte de ventas";
                    _cts4.Cancel();
                    break;

            }
            return Content("Generacion de Reporte Cancelada");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Te faltaria crear el token de cancelacion y pasarlo como parametro a tu metodo y cuando creas la tarea tambien se pasa como parametro. En el caso de querer cancelar una sola tarea cuando varias se ejecutan, deberias crear la cantidad de token necesarios para cada metodo.

Tenes que crear dos variables y luego un boton donde canceles la tarea.

```
CancellationTokenSource Cts;
CancellationToken ct;
CancellationTokenSource Cts2;
CancellationToken ct2;
```

En mi caso como prueba uso un comboBox para seleccionar que tarea cancelar.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Cts.Cancel();
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Cts2.Cancel(); 
        }
    }
  
    public ActionResult Report(ReportFilterModel filterModel, int report)
    {            
          Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
          Cts2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
          ct = Cts.Token;
          ct1 = Cts2.Token;

        if (Session["GeneratingReport"] == null || !(bool)Session["GeneratingReport"])
        {
            Session["GeneratingReport"] = true; //Se registra en sesión
            string basePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseFilePath"] + "/ReportesExcel/";
            string fileName = null;
            try {
                switch (report)
                {
                    case 1:
                        fileName = "report-users" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReport(filterModel, basePath + fileName, ct), ct);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fileName = "report-plays" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                       Task T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReportPlays(filterModel, basePath + fileName , ct2), ct2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fileName = "reporte-compras" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReportPurchases(filterModel, basePath + fileName, ct), ct);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fileName = "reporte-ventas-distribuidor" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhmmss") + ".xlsx";
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportReportDistributorPurchases(filterModel, basePath + fileName, ct), ct);
                        break;
                }
                Session["ReportPath"] = basePath + fileName;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
                string error =  ex.ToString();
            }
            
        }
        return Content("Generando Reporte");
    }
```

Los metodos que invoco tienen esta forma, aqui el ejemplo:

```
    public async Task ExportReport(ReportFilterModel filterModel, string path, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
          while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
          {
            using (var taskDb = new CmsLiteData()) //Se define contexto de ejecución de la conexión para la tarea Asyncrona, forzando la llamada de dispose cuando finalice
            {
                this.GenerateExcel(filterModel, "Informe compra y recompra (cantidad de usuarios únicos)", true, path, taskDb);
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CmsHelper.SetLog(ex.ToString(), 1, "PurchaseReportController", "ExportReport", "TareaAsincrona", "N/A", "N/A");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias Ramiro Barone ... Pruebo y te comento

Comment: Me falto decirte que deberias seleccionar a que metodo le pasas la cancelacion.

Comment: Sabes Ramiro Barone...Alli donde debo pasar la cancelacion al metodo especifico es algo que me causa la mayor confusion... si puedes extender tu respuesta con algo de codigo seria genial .. y te lo agradeceria muchisimo

Comment: ahora te modifico la respuesta.

Comment: Ramiro Barone...Tu pasas ct al metodo pero nunca el cts (CancellationTokenSource)

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC si, lo usas en el boton que te deje de muestra. Esta declarado al principio de todo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110613/discussion-between-ramiro-barone-and-efrain-mejias-c).

Comment: Ramiro Barone ... La verdad no me esta cancelando la tarea me devuelve un error de NUll , voy a editar la pregunta  para explicar en que punto estoy